# How to observe array property changes in RxSwift

Tags: swift, key-value-observing, rx-swift

Here is my class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   var myArray : NSArray!
}
```

I want to fire an event every time myArray points to a new array, like this:

```
self.myArray = ["a"]

self.myArray = ["b"]
```

I've tried rx_observe but failed, here is my code:

```
self.rx_observe(NSArray.self, "myArray").subscribeNext { (array) -> Void in
   print(array)
}
```

It only fires the first time, what's the problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most of the time, if you have control of the backing variable, you would prefer `Variable` to using `rx_observe`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   var myArray : Variable<NSArray>!
}
```

The first time you'll use myArray, you would asign it like so

```
myArray = Variable(["a"])
```

Then, if you want to change its value

```
myArray.value = ["b"]
```

And you can easily observe its changes, using

```
myArray.asObservable().subscribeNext { value in
  // ...
}
```

---

If you really want to use `rx_observe` (maybe because the variable is used elsewhere in your program and you don't want to change the API of your view controller), you would need to declare `myArray` as `dynamic` (another requirement is that the hosting class is a child of `NSObject`, here `UIViewController` satisfies this requirement). KVO is not implemented by default in swift, and using dynamic ensures access is done using the objective-c runtime, where KVO events are handled.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  dynamic var myArray: NSArray!
}
```

Documentation for this can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html)

Comment: use of variable gives this message from RXSwift library: "[DEPRECATED] `Variable` is planned for future deprecation. Please consider `BehaviorRelay` as a replacement. Read more at: https://git.io/vNqvx"

any idea of what else to use to observe an array?