# Is there a way to make observable enum in Swift (KVO)

Tags: swift, key-value-observing, rx-swift

I'm trying to use RxSwift for binding in MVVM.
I have a `Enum`:

```
enum Color : Int {
    case Red = 0, Green
}
```

and class for test

```
class Test : NSObject {
    var color: Color = .Red
    dynamic var test: String? {
        didSet {
            print("didSet \(test)")
        }
    }
}
```

And want to observe changes like:

```
test.rx_observe(Color.self, "color").subscribeNext { (color) -> Void in
     print("Observer \(color)")
}.addDisposableTo(bag)
```

But the program chashes with 
`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<RDProject.Test 0x7ff373513020> addObserver:<RxCocoa.KVOObserver 0x7ff37351a420> forKeyPath:@"color" options:5 context:0x0] was sent to an object that is not KVC-compliant for the "color" property.'`

Code for simple `String` works:

```
test.rx_observe(String.self, "test").subscribeNext { string in
     print("Observer \(string)")
}.addDisposableTo(bag)

test.test = "1"
test.test = "2"
```

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766600/how-to-observe-array-property-changes-in-rxswift/35792203#35792203) that to make class inherited not from `NSObject` I should make it `dynamic`, but I can't make `Enum` dynamic.
Is there a way to make `Enum` observable?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use KVO for this task.
Just use a BehaviorSubject like this:

Create a private Field like this one:

```
let colorSubject = BehaviorSubject<Color?>(value: nil)
```

Then you have a property like this which informs the BehaviorSubject that the value did change.

```
var color : Color? {
    didSet {
        colorSubject.onNext(color)
    }
}
```

To subscribe to any change use an equivalent statement to this one:

```
let disposable = colorSubject.subscribeNext { (color: Color?) -> Void in
    // Do something with it.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your enum is of type `Int`, you can make it objective-c compatible by marking it with `@objc`. Doing this will make compiler ok with marking the property as `dynamic`. For the property to be KVO compliant, it'll also need to be anotated with `@objc`.

```
@objc enum Color : Int {
    case Red = 0, Green
}

class Test : NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var color: Color = .Red
    dynamic var test: String? {
        didSet {
            print("didSet \(test)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I'm using Swift 5 and tried this solution. Unfortunately it crashes with `Fatal error: Could not extract a String from KeyPath Swift.ReferenceWritableKeyPath ... `
Could you confirm this still works?

Comment: It indeed crashes, but annotating the field with `@objc` fixes the crash and makes this functionning again. I updated my answer to reflect this. Hope it help :)

Comment: Thanks for the response! 
---
This indeed fixes the problem. First of all, it's an enum of type `Error`, changing that to `Int` is the first step.
---
Then, annotating both the enum and property with `@objc` are the is the last step for making this work.
--- And then a problem I still have is the the property is `MyEnumType?`, so an Optional. This can't be represented in Objective-C. I don't think that can be solved. But you answered my question, and this works :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest only make a proxy variable and use KVO on it.

```
class Model: NSObject {

    enum Color: Int {
        case Red = 0, Green
    }

    dynamic var colorRaw: Int?
    var color: Color = .Red {
        didSet {
            colorRaw = color.rawValue
        }
    }

}
```

More details here - https://christiantietze.de/posts/2015/05/observing-enum-swift-kvo/

Answer (score 0):

If your applications's minimum supported version of iOS is 13.0 or newer you can use Combine and make the property `@Published`

```
class Test : NSObject {
    @Published var color: Color = .Red

    dynamic var test: String? {
        didSet {
            print("didSet \(test)")
        }
    }
}
```

and observe it like this:

```
let test = Test()
test.$color.sink(receiveValue: { color in
    print(color)
})
```